# need help on ajax when same function with ajax call is called continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need assistance on ajax because I am new to it. When same ajax call is called multiple times before that ajax call completes execution its throwing empty pop up on ui. How can I solve this problem. Actually when user clicks on download link that code is written in success function of ajax. But if user clicks the download link multiple times before downloading the first one. Its throwing error. How can i solve this?

this is my code

```
function clickLink(section) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'MyService.asmx/getMetrics',
        data: { programName: progName, startYear: beginYear, endYear: endYear, userName: spnUserName.innerHTML, rdate:dt },
        success: function (data) {
            var jdata = data;
            jdata = jdata.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
            jdata = jdata.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '');
            jdata = jdata.replace('\r\n', '');        
            var link = document.createElement("a");           
            link.setAttribute('href', jdata.trim());
            link.onclick = OpenFile(jdata.trim());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's throwing empty window because the call does not succeed and `alertThrown` presumably is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a temporary class.

```
$('.your-element:not(.disabled)').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('disabled');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'MyService.asmx/getMetrics',
        data: { programName: progName, startYear: beginYear, endYear: endYear, userName: spnUserName.innerHTML, rdate:dt },
        success: function (data) {
            var jdata = data;
            jdata = jdata.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
            jdata = jdata.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '');
            jdata = jdata.replace('\r\n', '');        
            var link = document.createElement("a");           
            link.setAttribute('href', jdata.trim());
            link.onclick = OpenFile(jdata.trim());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }).done(function(){
       $this.removeClass('disabled');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your ajax function into a variable, then use a function and check if the variable is defined or not:

```
var xhr;
function CallAjax(){
    if( xhr !== undefined ) return false;
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'MyService.asmx/getMetrics',
        data: { programName: progName, startYear: beginYear, endYear: endYear, userName: spnUserName.innerHTML, rdate:dt },
        success: function (data) {
            var jdata = data;
            jdata = jdata.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
            jdata = jdata.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '');
            jdata = jdata.replace('\r\n', '');        
            var link = document.createElement("a");           
            link.setAttribute('href', jdata.trim());
            link.onclick = OpenFile(jdata.trim());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: PD: You can use this solution to abort current ajax calls. Just type `xhr.abort()` if xhr is already defined